# how can i get and set generic values with string identifiers

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I always run in circles with this problem. i wrote code that uses the following interface:

```
public interface IStorage
{
    T GetElement<T>(String id) where T : class;
    void SetElement<T>(String id, T element) where T : class;
}
```

But i am just not able to write generic get and set functions. I always end up trying to access dictionaries but all my attempts never even compile. I am mising something huge here, what is it?

Comment: Can you show an attempt at implementing this interface that we can use as a starting point?

Comment: Posting your last failed attempt would help enormously, because fixing errors is much easier than writing code from scratch. Most likely, you have a small syntax error that can be fixed with a few keystrokes.

Comment: Not really clear what you want to do. Do you want to have an interface that will let you set any property on a class that implements your interface? If so, you should probably look into Reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you defined the interface, method invocation on an interface implementation requires specification of the base type `<T>`. At that point, you might as well be casting.

**[Edited to note]** Also, the base class for a *generic method* is scoped to the individual method, not to the class/interface, which is probably what was causing your problems.

First off, I'd simplify your interface to something like this:

```
public interface IStorage<T> where T : class
{
  T this[ string id ] { get ; set ; }
}
```

Then I'd implement it something like:

```
public class Repository : IStorage<Widget>
{
  private IDictionary<string,Widget> backingStore = new Dictionary<string,Widget>() ;

  public Widget this[string id]
  {
  get
    {
      Widget instance ;
      bool   exists   = backingStore.TryGetValue(id, out instance ) ;
      return instance ; // null if the dictionary doesn't contain the key
    }
  set
    {
      if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id) ) throw new ArgumentException("id") ;
      if ( value == null                 ) throw new ArgumentNullException("value") ;
      backingStore.Add( id , value ) ;
      return ;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: meanwhile i was able to implement something myself - but this is awsome... i will change my implementation - thx :)

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do what you want to do, but you need to use something other than a dictionary. Nicholas Carey's answer is better to do, but I had already started on this, so I'll leave this for the future in case someone really does need to know how to use the interface you provided:

### Code

```
public interface IStorage
{
    T GetElement<T>(string id) where T : class;
    void SetElement<T>(string id, T element) where T : class;
}

public class StorageImpl : IStorage
{
    private Hashtable _hashTable = new Hashtable();

    public T GetElement<T>(string id) where T : class
    {
        var hashObject = _hashTable[id];

        if (hashObject.GetType() == typeof(T))
        {
            return (T)hashObject;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(
                String.Format("Item ID: {0} was of type {1}. Expecting type {2}",
                    id, hashObject.GetType(), typeof(T)));
        }   
    }

    public void SetElement<T>(string id, T element) where T : class
    {
        lock (_hashTable.SyncRoot)
        {
            _hashTable[id] = element;
        }
    }
}

public static void RunSnippet()
{
    IStorage storage = new StorageImpl();

    storage.SetElement<string>("something", "string object");
    storage.SetElement<Exception>("someexception", new Exception("some exception message"));

    Console.WriteLine(storage.GetElement<string>("something"));
    Console.WriteLine(storage.GetElement<Exception>("someexception").Message);
    // Throws exception
    Console.WriteLine(storage.GetElement<string>("someexception"));
}
```

### Output

```
string object
some exception message
---
The following error occurred while executing the snippet:
System.Exception: Item ID: someexception was of type System.Exception. Expecting type System.String
```